# Fast updating GUI window with a second thread crashes by resizing or moving the window

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have an image acquisition thread that is updating GUI per each grab in a 64-bit Qt 5.6.0 application compiled with Visual Studio 2015. Unless user does not resize or move the GUI window, the application is working fine. But if the window is moved or resized, it randomly crashes. Code summary is following.

According to debugging information, the crash happens because of access violation in `QImage::convertToFormat_helper` Anybody knows why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

**Initialization:**
`

```
auto thread = new KinectThread();
connect(thread,SIGNAL(OnRgbImage(QImage)),this,SLOT(rgbImageReady(QImage)));
thread->start();
```

`

**Worker thread:**
`

```
void KinectThread::run()
{
    kinect = new Kinect();

    while(true)
    {
        auto img = kinect->getRgb();
        QImage imgIn= QImage((uchar*) img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        emit OnRgbImage(imgIn);
        QThread::msleep(20);
    }

    delete kinect;
}
```

`

**GUI Update:**

```
void MainWindow::rgbImageReady(QImage image)
{
    if (!image.isNull())
    {
        QGraphicsView* view = ui->graphicsView;
        auto width = image.width();
        auto height = image.height();
        m_pScene->setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height);
        auto pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
        m_pixmapItem->setPixmap(pixmap);
        view->show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line gives you the error ?

Comment: Not sure, but possibly it happens because image showing much slower then fetching of image and a lot of image objects stays in queue? Try to check this with some counters or whatever. Or `kinect->getRgb();` is slow operation? Anyway it is not so good idea to send QImage object over the signal, better to use some common pointer and threads synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QImage` constructors taking `uchar *data` for the image data do not create a copy of the data, meaning that they require the `uchar *` buffer to live at least as long as the QImage instance.

Additionally, `QImage` is [implicitly shared](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), meaning that copying a `QImage` does not copy the image data either, but still accesses the original buffer.

That is good in the way that copying the image and passing it through the signal is fast. But it also means that the image data from the `kinect->getRgb()` call must live until the signal event has been passed through the event queue to `MainWindow::rgbImageReady` and until this has finished using the data. It also means that if the `Kinect` class changes the existing buffer that has been passed to `rgbImageReady`, while you create a pixmap from the image with `QPixmap::fromImage(image)`, you'll get a mess. And you'll get an access violation if the `Kinect` class deletes the existing buffer (for example because it allocates a larger buffer because the window size changed) before `rgbImageReady` finished with the previous buffer.

Comment: If `kinect->getRgb()` creates a copy of the buffer, are you deleting this anywhere? `QImage` does not take ownership of the buffer that you pass into the constructor. (You can pass a cleanup function to it though, to delete the buffer when the last `QImage` copy is destroyed, but it doesn't look like you currently do that.)

Comment: QImage or buffer were being destroyed. But by considering your hint that QImage does not take ownership, I determined destruction of the QImage data is immature in the second thread.  Thus, passing deep copy of the `QImage` into the signal fixed the problem. `emit OnRgbImage(imgIn.copy());` Thanks for considering this problem together.

Answer (score 0):

By considering @E4Z9's hint that QImage does not take ownership of its data, it was then obvious that destruction of the QImage data was immature in the second thread.  Thus, passing deep copy of the `QImage` into the signal fixed the problem.

`emit OnRgbImage(imgIn.copy());`

So it was a problem of immature object destruction which was exposed with unrelated resizing and moving of window.